# What's wrong with this migrated post revision link?

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, migrated-questions

If you visit [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30933651/960757) and follow the link from this message:

> **migration rejected** from [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/287280/revisions) 16
>   hours ago
>
> This question came from our site for professional programmers
>   interested in conceptual questions about software development. Votes,
>   comments, and answers are locked due to the question being closed
>   here, but it may be eligible for editing and reopening on the site
>   where it originated.

You'll end up with 404. The problem is that the post ID is wrong there. It should have been 287281, not 287280. So instead of:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/287280/revisions

should be:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/287281/revisions

Could you check what happened there?

<sup>I haven't checked another posts in the same state as I don't know how to easily find some.</sup>

Comment: 287281 says it was merged with 287280. That may be related, although the merge destination is clearly 287281.

Comment: @BoltClock, yep, that might well be. Btw. isn't that question deadlocked somehow on SO (if the original question has been merged into a newer post)? I guess that 287280 contained only the code and 287281 just the error message. But migrated to SO was only 287280 (that no loger exists).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone got too clever with merges and migrations.

The solution, as usual, is to delete everything. Done.

Comment: Yay, when can we delete SO?

Comment: @bjb568 as soon as DD fixes all its bugs